# HTML5 and Video capturing possibilies in all the Browsers and platforms

Tags: ios, html, cross-browser, video-capture, getusermedia

I have started to search the video recording possibilities using HTML5 for past few months. But i could find it is possible only in `opera` and `chrome` using `getUserMedia()` in desktop browser and i'm not aware of mobile browsers.Since HTML5 is booming now very well. Can anyone please let me know the video recording is possible in HTML5 with all the desktop and mobile browsers?. If possible please explain me how?.... and please let me know what are the possibilities for video capturing using HTML5 for all the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment the best compatibility is offered by Chrome (both desktop and mobile versions) and Firefox (just the desktop version).

Opera also has support for `getUserMedia()` but other than that the rest of APIs are not supported by Opera.

Several attempts already exist for recording video directly from the browser, but there is no standard established for now.

There's a good article on the state of video and audio capturing with HTML5 that i recommend you read: http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording

Also if you wish you can view some demos that the webRTC experiment is currently developing:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work for Ziggeo.

WebRTC support is currently limited to Chrome, Opera and Firefox with varying degree of support:

- Firefox allows you to record video+audio as webm blob and send it to your servers
- Chrome and Opera provide access to the video frames and the audio signal, so you need to encode yourself in JS, send it to your servers and splice it together

For all other browsers and older versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera, you are required to fall back to Flash, resulting in flv files being transmitted via RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" capture="capture">
```

2. Allowing both images and videos

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*,image/*">
```

3. For multiple files

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" multiple>
```

[Image show the supported browsers and versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSmwN.png)